# Is there a limit to the amount of arguments I can pass to a method?

Tags: objective-c, arguments

I am just wondering if there is a limit to the amount of arguments I can pass to a method in Objective-C using the following style:

```
- (void)example:(int)i forTime:(int)i forDate:(NSDate *)date etc etc
```

This is of course hypothetical, but I just find it interesting to know the reason behind such limitations (for example the character limit in URL's and such), and I love to see other people's opinions on questions like these on StackOverflow

And even with a limit on the number of arguments allowed to be passed, would it still be possible to pass `NSArray`'s containing objects as arguments and then just call on these objects from the array in the method using `objectAtIndex`?

Comment: I'm sure there's some sort of a line length limit in the compilers.

Comment: (And you could always write a test program to find the limit -- have it construct dummy programs with successively longer parm lists and try compiling/running them.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I quickly wrote a short program in C to generate a test method and call based on the desired inputted number of arguments, as per Hot Licks suggestion. Just made a method that takes 1,000 NSNumber arguments and it worked fine. Took up two pages in Xcode on my monitor, but it ran with no warnings or anything. Might try 10,000 later, but it seems there are no limits other than any imposed by hardware capabilities, etc.

Answer (score 0):

No there is no limit to the number of arguments

The only limiting factor is the stack size of the process on a given architecture since method parameters are put on the stack.

Comment: Do you have anything to back that up?

Comment: besides the fact that this a really stupid question - since anyone who would write code that would test this limit doesnt know how to write code, the only limit on argument passing is generally the stack size of the process, also the stack size of the compiler process if exceeded could cause a compilation failure.

Comment: I think most of us can agree the answer to this question is obvious, but as you can see by the amount of upvotes the asker has received, apparently people think it's a decent question. Answering without any source (esp. when testing this takes all of five minutes) is just begging for someone to ask you to prove it. But, yes, you are right. As long as you don't end up with a _Stack Overflow_ you should be okay. :p